# When does a variable copy be released in lambda function?

Tags: c++, memory, lambda

As the example below, I define 2 variables x and y. When I call the lambda function twice, it seems like it will not destroy the copy. From [11.14 — Lambda captures | Learn C++ - Learn C++](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/lambda-captures/), it says:

> Because captured variables are members of the lambda object, their values are persisted across multiple calls to the lambda!

How does C++ manage the memory for lambda function?

```cpp
int main() {
    int x = 1;
    static int y = 1;
    auto fun = [=]() mutable{
        x++;
        y++;
        cout<<"Inside:\t\t";
        cout<<"x:"<<x<<"\t"<<"y:"<<y<<endl;
    };

    for (int i = 0; i<2; i++) {
        fun();
        cout<<"Outside:\t";
        cout<<"x:"<<x<<"\t"<<"y:"<<y<<endl<<endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```sh
Inside:         x:2     y:2
Outside:        x:1     y:2

Inside:         x:3     y:3
Outside:        x:1     y:3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It stores it inside the object itself.  Another way to think of your lambda is below.  This is "kind of" equivalent to what the compiler is generating, and yes, I'm changing scopes around a bit and I know that, but this may be clearer to a beginner at C++.

```cpp
static int y = 1; // Moved this out from main
class my_lambda{
public:
my_lambda(int x) : _x(x) {}
~my_lambda() = default;
void operator()()
{
  _x++;
  y++;
  cout<<"Inside:\t\t";
  cout<<"_x:"<<_x<<"\t"<<"y:"<<y<<endl;
}

private:
int _x;
};

int main() {
    int x = 1;
    my_lambda fun{x}; // "Captures" x

    for (int i = 0; i<2; i++) {
        fun();
        cout<<"Outside:\t";
        cout<<"x:"<<x<<"\t"<<"y:"<<y<<endl<<endl;
    }
}
```

As you can hopefully see, the "fake lambda" class I made is doing the same thing your actual lambda is.  It "captures" `x` as part of its constructor and copies it to internal storage, which I called `_x`.  And y is just in scope for it, though I moved to global to be above the class declaration.

I'm overloading the `()` operator to make a class that's callable, which is a normal thing to do in some circumstances.  See operator [overloading](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) if you wish for more information.

So this is "kind of, sorta" how lambdas work.  They take your body and put it into the `operator()` of the object that's generated, and anything captured is one of the object's variables, with either the actual object (if by value) or a reference, if captured that way.

And to *directly* answer your question: when `fun` goes out of scope, it is freed, both in a lambda, and my case.

Comment: Thank you Kevin! I'm so appreciated. It's so brilliant that you use class object to explain this concept. Very clear and intuitive .

Comment: I'm glad this was helpful to you.  I find it helps for a lot of "magic" the compiler does to attempt to deconstruct it down to "how would I do this if I had to implement it myself?"  That doesn't 100% work, but often re-writing in a simple way something the compiler is ultra-optimizing can help you understand what's happening.  Above is how I mostly "conceptualize" lambdas.  It's not perfect, and definitely not in efficiency the same as what the compiler does, but it gets the point across for variable lifetimes and such, which was the focus of your question.